# Xcode linking error with realm

Tags: ios, xcode, realm

I am receiving this linking error in Xcode for the Realm Framework files.  I have searched and found users with similar errors with other frameworks.  However, I have tried to apply the solutions but nothing seems to work.  I haven't found any solutions for a recent version of Xcode.

The this only occurs when building for my device.  Everything works in the iOS Simulator.

```
ld: warning: ignoring file /Users/Developer/Swift/App/RealmSwift.framework/RealmSwift, missing required architecture armv7 in file /Users/Developer/Swift/RealmSwift.framework/RealmSwift (2 slices)
ld: warning: ignoring file /Users/Developer/Swift/Realm.framework/Realm, missing required architecture armv7 in file /Users/Developer/Swift/Realm.framework/Realm (2 slices)
Undefined symbols for architecture armv7:
```

---

I am using:

- Xcode 6.3.2 Swift
- Realm Swift 0.93.1

Answer (score 1):

I removed all of the frameworks then dragged them back in to the project.  I had to create an empty Frameworks folder below RealmSwift.Framework/Headers (Not in the installation instructions on the Realm site).  Everything is now compiling on my device.